# [UIGestureDelayedTouch _didEndScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ac52d0

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am having the error which is in the title of the question:
`[UIGestureDelayedTouch _didEndScroll:]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ac52d0

It occurs when I click on the button OR on the table cell.
Trying to debug it I cleared out that this error occurs before the functions that are called when the button/cell is clicked. But after the app is loaded. I.e. the app is working fine untill I make a click, so I cannot locate the code responsible for this error.

I know there are plenty of questions concerning unrecognized selectors and I DID look through them, but I could not find the solution to mine.
And what's more devastating I have no idea what `UIGestureDelayTouch` and `_DidEndScroll` are.

In the program I did not implement neither gestures support, nor any scroll views.
Will be thankful for any ideas on why this might be happening.

Comment: If you are seeing didEndScroll, you definitely have a scroll view in some form. Are you using a UITableView or UICollectionView?

Comment: Yes, there is an UITableView (and I did nothing with its internal scroll view).

Comment: Could you provide some code? Stack trace from your debug console?